# Getting ClassNotFoundException while setting up Spring 4.0 Simple project Setup

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dispatch

I'm setting up a simple project with Spring 4. I'm not using Maven. Instead I've simply added the Spring Dependencies by adding the Jars to the classpath.
I'm using RAD 8.5 and Websphere 8.5 for this project.

When I am trying to start up the project, it is giving error:
class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

I've provided the following in the web.xml:

```
<servlet>
        <display-name>Controller</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

My Controller-servlet.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"   
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd"> 

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring4.controller" />
    <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

My Controller class looks like:

```
@Controller
public class HelloSpring4Controller {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")    
      public ModelAndView sayHello() {    
       String message = "Welcome to Spring 4.0 !!! ";    
       return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);    
      } 
}
```

I have a welcome.jsp under WEB-INF/view where I'm fetching the value put in message Object.

Can someone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,
Sayantani

Comment: evidently however you added the jars to the classpath didn't work.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Spring Boot and Maven or Gradle?

Comment: Nathan, since the Controller servlet contains classes from the spring package, I can understand that the jars have been added correctly. The classes are not showing any error. Even when I click on org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet, in the web.xml, it is redirecting me to the Dispatcher Class, though I cannot see the source.

Comment: Chrylis, There is no such reason as to why I'm not using Maven or gradle, but my development tool is RAD 8.5 and I could not find enough support document to use Maven from RAD.

Comment: Isn't RAD based on Eclipse? Maven is thoroughly supported with m2eclipse.

Comment: And you have added the jars to the compile-time classpath, but clearly not runtime.

Comment: But does that have any thing to do with this error??

Comment: I've created a user library with spring jars and added to my java build path. I am unable to understand where am going wrong.

Comment: that's an important detail you should add to the question. (as a comment it's not visible enough.)

Comment: Try adding it to your manifest.mf in META-INF folder.